# How to call onmouseover event of a div from a function inside a Namespace?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
var FOO = FOO || {};

FOO.Main = (function() {

    function init() {
             // do some not relevant stuff
    }

    // User interaction
    function mouseOver() {
        console.log("OVER");
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        console.log("OUT");
    }

    init();
})();
```

And this on the html:

```
<div id="logo-container" onmouseover="NARDOVE.mouseOver();" onmouseout="NARDOVE.Main.mouseOut();">
        <div id="layer-1">
            <canvas id="logo-canvas"></canvas>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/labs-logo.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I get the following errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'mouseOver' (index):23
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'mouseOut' of undefined

I know I'm calling the methods differently but  that is just me testing, any ideas how can I call the mouse methods using the div inline calls?

Comment: Those functions are local to the closure, you'd have to return an object. Read about the "module pattern", I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you define your namespace. You assign the result of an anonymous function call to FOO.Main, but your anonymous function doesn't return anything.

You can fix this by returning an object containing the methods and properties you want to expose publicly via FOO.Main:

```
var FOO = FOO || {};

FOO.Main = (function() {
    function init() {
             // do some not relevant stuff
    }

    // User interaction
    function mouseOver() {
        console.log("OVER");
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        console.log("OUT");
    }

    init();

    return {
        "mouseOver": mouseOver,            
        "mouseOut": mouseOut
    };
})();
```

You can then call your mouseOver/mouseOut functions like this:

```
FOO.Main.mouseOver();
FOO.Main.mouseOut();
```

Comment: Thanks it works! now may I ask is this common practice? I just want to adopt best practices while I'm in the learning curve

Comment: @RicardoSanchez Yes, it is a very common way to define namespaces, though not the only one. What you are doing is called the module design pattern and if you want to read more about modules, I suggest you read [this article](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/).